# How to convert a dask dataframe to a dictionary using dataframe column values as keys

Tags: dictionary, dask-dataframe

import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col_2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

{k: g[df.columns[1]].tolist() for k,g in df.groupby(df.columns[0])}

{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}

from dask.dataframe import from_pandas

ddf = from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

{k: g[ddf.columns[1]].tolist() for k,g in ddf.groupby(ddf.columns[0])}

NotImplementedError: Iteration of DataFrameGroupBy objects requires computing the groups which may be slow. You probably want to use 'apply' to execute a function for all the columns. To access individual groups, use 'get_group'. To list all the group names, use 'df[].unique().compute()'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be simplified using [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) on Dask. This solution might be faster (not entirely sure) because it just uses Dask mapPartition with some conversions under the hood.

For example:

First, some setup

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'col_2': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

And then we define the logic. This will perform the operation for one partition of data. The type hints inform Fugue how to bring this back to a Dask DataFrame. When we execute this, we will partition the data first.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Dict, List, Any
def logic(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Iterable[Dict[str,Any]]:
    yield {"key": df.iloc[0]['col_1'], "values": df['col_2'].tolist()}
```

Now all we need to do is call Fugue and run this:

```py
from fugue import transform
res = transform(ddf, 
                logic, 
                schema="key:str, values:[int]", 
                partition={"by": "col_1"}, 
                engine="dask")
res.compute()
```

Schema is a requirement to avoid inference. Partition will make this operation happen on each partition of data. This will run on "dask" because of the engine we supplied. If no engine is passed, it will run on Pandas.

And then you get:

```
key values
b   [3, 4]
a   [1, 2]
```